# Конфликт 2 библиотек. ProGuard не пропускает

Tags: android

Proguard-prop

```
   # Keep JWPlayer
-dontwarn com.longtailvideo.jwplayer.cast.*
-dontwarn com.longtailvideo.jwplayer.*

# Keep Picasso
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**

#GSON
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }

#Firebase
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.**
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
```

---

Ошибка при компиляции с ProGuard

```
Warning:com.google.ads.afma.nano.NanoAdshieldEvent$AdShieldEvent: can't find referenced field 'int zzbqb' in program class com.google.ads.afma.nano.NanoAdshieldEvent$AdShieldEvent
Warning:com.google.ads.afma.nano.NanoAfmaSignals$AFMASignals: can't find referenced field 'int zzbqb' in program class com.google.ads.afma.nano.NanoAfmaSignals$AFMASignals
Warning:com.google.ads.afma.nano.NanoAfmaSignals$AdSignalsContainer: can't find referenced field 'int zzbqb' in program class com.google.ads.afma.nano.NanoAfmaSignals$AdSignalsContainer
Warning:there were 3 unresolved references to program class members.
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForDebug'.
> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

Чего он хочет?

Comment: а что с чем конфликтует?

Comment: Почти наверняка не хватает какой-то зависимости из плей сервисов